# How do I install opencv on pypy3?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pypy

Anyone help me with this fail report. I am trying to install opencv on pypy3 with git folder and `pypy3 setup.py install` https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python

```
[100%] Building CXX object 
modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/__/src2/cv2.cpp.o
/home/toso/Dev/Python/Pypy3/opencv_test/opencv- 
python/opencv/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp:17:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file 
or directory
17 | #include <Python.h>
   |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/build.make:76: 
 modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/__/src2/cv2.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2254: 
 modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:166: all] Error 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/toso/Dev/Python/Pypy3/opencv_test/site- 
  packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 589, in setup
   cmkr.make(make_args, env=env)
  File "/home/toso/Dev/Python/Pypy3/opencv_test/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", 
  line 507, in make
   os.path.abspath(CMAKE_BUILD_DIR())))

An error occurred while building with CMake.
  Command:
    cmake --build . --target install --config Release --
  Source directory:
    /home/toso/Dev/Python/Pypy3/opencv_test/opencv-python
Working directory:
    /home/toso/Dev/Python/Pypy3/opencv_test/opencv-python/_skbuild/linux-x86_64- 
    3.6/cmake-build
Please see CMake's output for more information.
```

Comment: Have you checked the pip version you currently have? Try to upgrade pip at first.

Comment: I have pip  21.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have numpy and matplotlib installed first, type the following into the command line.

```
pip install numpy
pip install matplotlib
```

Next we are going to install Open-CV

1. Go to this website [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv)
2. Download the file `opencv_python-4.5.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl`. If your using a different version of Python not 3.9 then download the file for your python version. The `cp39‑cp39` part of the whl's file name is the python version number that wheel is for. The `win_amd64` part would be the operating system type, so amd64 would be 64 bit.
3. Open the command line, navigate to your downloads folder or whichever location you downloaded the file too, for me for example it would be `cd D:\Downloads`.
4. next type `pip install opencv_python-4.5.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl`
   The file should install correctly and you will get a message like this:

```
D:\Downloads>pip install opencv_python-4.5.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
Processing d:\downloads\opencv_python-4.5.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: opencv-python
  Attempting uninstall: opencv-python
    Found existing installation: opencv-python 4.4.0.46
    Uninstalling opencv-python-4.4.0.46:
      Successfully uninstalled opencv-python-4.4.0.46
Successfully installed opencv-python-4.5.2

D:\Downloads>
```

Comment: Yes, but I have linux not windows and i am trying to install opencv on pypy3 not for python but I thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get pypy? If it is from `apt install pypy3` then you also need the `pypy3-dev` package. Note this is probably going to be painful, since the version available there is quite old. I would strongly advise using the conda packages which already provide binary packages where possible, and moving to pypy3.7 since pypy3.6 is not supported anymore. From the command line, once you have conda installed, do

```
conda config --set channel_priority strict
conda create -n conda-pypy pypy3.7=7.3.4
conda activate conda-pypy
conda install opencv
```

We are rolling out support for v7.3.5, so you have to specify 7.3.4 for now. Hopefully that restriction should be removed soon.

Comment: I install pypy3 7.3.4, and this command didnt work conda create -n conda-pypy pypy3.7=7.3.4. I have this failure report PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels: - pypy3

Comment: I figured out how to create a virtual environment with pypy3 7.3.4. But conda install opencv didn't work for me. I instaled then i type pip list but opencv not there.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a line: conda config --add channels conda-forge

Comment: I install opencv with git and it is work but when I launch some program text me:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("test", image)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2) /home/toso/Documents/opencv-python/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:679: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'

Comment: That is a consequence of building from source. It is worth the effort to get the conda version going.